# How to set the absolute width and height for outlook addin dialog?

Tags: modal-dialog, outlook-web-addins

I want to set the fix value for dialog width and height while using  officeUI.displayDialogAsync,How can I achieve that?

```js
officeUI.displayDialogAsync(link, { height: 768, width: 584, promptBeforeOpen: false, displayInIframe: true }, function (asyncResult) {
  var dialogObj = asyncResult.value;
  dialogObj.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, function (dialogEvent) {
   event.completed();
  });
 });
```

The width and height here is percentage value for current browser per documentation. Can I have a fix value height and width?

Comment: Latest comment on the issue  is on 2018, no update after that. May be you can comment. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/8892379-adjust-taskpane-width and also there is this one https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/257

Answer (score 0):

Currently this functionality is not part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please vote for this feature [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34701499-allow-dialogs-to-be-sized-with-pixels-instead-of-o). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.